# Відповідник до слова "букмекер"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Букме́кер — людина, чиєю професією є отримувати гроші від тих, хто робить ставки ([Вікіпедія](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80)). Походить від англ. "bookmaker", де слово "book" можна перекласти як "домовлятися", "бронювати", "записувати", "замовляти", а "maker" - "творець", "фабрикант", "виробник" (ГуглПерекладач).

Приклад вживання:

> Більше 200 букмекерських контор світу представлені й оцінені в нашому
>   рейтингу.

Отож, на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bukmeker) іще не обрали єдиного варіанту, однак там пропонують варіант "ставкар", але такого слова немає в СУМі, проте там є слово "[ставка](http://sum.in.ua/s/stavka)". Проте якщо використати це слово як відповідник, то як бути із "букмекерськими конторами"? "Контори для ставок" чи "ставкарські контори"? З іншими варіантами, такими як "ставкотрим" та "ставкотримач" також складно утворити хороші прикметники.

Чи є в нашій мові якийсь відповідник, яким би можна було замінити це слово, а також від якого можна було б утворити прикметник до слова "букмекерський"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Британською англійською букмекерів також іноді називають словосполученням *turf accountant* (можливо, це словосполучення частково застаріло, але словники його все ще наводять). Тут під *turf* мається на увазі «дерен (шар трави на ґрунті)» або «ділянка землі, покрита дерном» (часто дерном покривають землю для кінних перегонів або інших змагань), також це слово поширилося до значень «доріжка для перегонів» і «кіні перегони»; *accountant* — «бухгалтер». Відповідно, можна спробувати змайструвати щось на зразок *перегонний бухгалтер* чи *бухгалтер перегонів*, *дерновий бухгалтер*; якщо Ви хочете позбутися й слова *бухгалтер*, то можете спробувати замінити *бухгалтер* на *рахівник*.
2. Також можна спробувати за прямим значенням: *приймач ставок* (*ставкоприймач*), *реєстратор ставок* (*ставкореєстратор*), *ставкар*.

Але слово *букмекер*, як цілком правильно [зазначає Марія Мацкевич](/a/4792), зафіксоване в усіх словниках — тому вигадувати інші варіанти, мені здається, є сенс лише через теоретичний інтерес (на практиці ці варіанти можуть бути менш зрозумілими за запозичене *букмекер*).

Answer (score 2):

**СУМ-20** містить такі визначення.

> ***[БУКМЕКЕР](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=153095&page=217)***  а, ч. Той, хто приймає грошові ставки у грі в тоталізатор. *У всіх країнах легальний податок, який платять
>   організатори спортивних тоталізаторів, йде саме на той спорт, на якому
>   заробляють букмекери* (з наук.-попул. літ.).
>
> ***[БУКМЕКЕРСЬКИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=153096&page=217)*** а, е. Прикм. до букме́кер. *Букмекерський бізнес в Україні активно включився у прогнозування політичних подій*
>   (з газ.).

**Словник іншомовних слів Мельничука**

> ***[Букмекер](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53393/278982.html)***(англ. *book-maker*, від *book* – записувати і *maker* – агент)
>   у буржуазних країнах особа, яка збирає і записує застави від публіки
>   при укладенні парі на кінних змаганнях.

**Eкономічна енциклопедія**

> ***[БУКМЕКЕР](http://slovopedia.org.ua/38/53393/377786.html)*** (англ. *bookmaker*) — службова особа в ігровому бізнесі, яка приймає грошові ставки від гравців на тоталізаторі.

**ВТССУМ**

> ***[Букмекер](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/834360.html)*** -а, ч. Особа, яка збирає і записує ставки у грі в тоталізатор.
>
> ***[Букмекерський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53393/834361.html)*** -а, -е. Стос. до букмекера.

**Орфографічний словник української мови**

> ***[Букме́кер](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53393/45833.html)*** іменник чоловічого роду, істота. Той, хто приймає ставки на спортивні змагання
>
> ***[Букме́керський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53393/45834.html)*** прикметник

Обидва слова цілком нормативні, адже присутні в декількох академічних виданнях. Отже, можемо використовувати в діловому мовленні. Непотрібно вигадувати заміну словам, які вже є в словниках.